# Endless reboots after adb remount on Docker Android 10 emulator

Tags: boot-loop, android-emulator, android-10

I'm trying to remount the system partition of an Android docker emulator (stable v.30.2.5 x86_64). I use the official docker scripts from the [Google docker scripts page](https://github.com/google/android-emulator-container-scripts). According to the official documentation remounting the system partition can be done with the `adb remount /system` command so I tried that out but got stuck in a endless reboot of the emulator. I did the following:

1. Start the docker Android emulator with `./run.sh f47fab55785d -writable-system`
2. Connect the device with adb: `adb connect`
3. Root the emulator: `adb root`
4. Remount the system partition:

   ```
   adb remount /                                 
   Disabling verity for /system
   Using overlayfs for /system
   Now reboot your device for settings to take effect
   remount succeeded
   ```
5. Reboot: `adb reboot`

All the commands seem to work as expected and the emulator starts to reboot. However, the emulator gets stuck in an endless loop after some seconds (see logs).

[image]

In the logs I see two errors but I don't understand what's causing the reboot. Does anyone know what's causing this endless reboots and how I can remount the system partition?

```
kernel: [   11.379317] init: [libfs_mgr]check_fs(): mount(/dev/block/pci/pci0000:00/0000:00:06.0/by-name/metadata,/metadata,ext4)=-1: No such file or directory

kernel: [   13.506403] cfg80211: failed to load regulatory.db
```

Comment: `regulatory.db` seems to be the database where for each country in the world the allowed Wifi frequencies are stored in. Based on the provided log you did not cleanly shut-down the emulator file-system. May be something got corrupted in the file-system and thus this database got corrupted.

Comment: If I stop the container and start again the emulator starts normally again but does not mount the system partition in read/write. Since I used adb reboot it should reboot with the normal routine.

Comment: I don't have much docker experience but from what I know restarting a  docker image means loosing all changes. My advice: just use the Android emulator without docker unless you are an Docker expert and exactly know what you are doing.

Comment: If I could go without docker I would do it, but in this case it is a must to use it.